# null pointer exception while generating custom toast

Tags: android

i am generating a custom toast with different images depending on which button is pressed by the user
"toastdesign" is the xml layout file which contains the design of toast.
 but the app crashes when i click on any of the textview and the log cat generates null pointer exception. plz help????

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (v.getId() == R.id.tv1) {
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }

    else if (v.getId() == R.id.tv2) {
        image = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.edc);
    }
    iv.setImageBitmap(image);
    toast.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toastdesign, null));
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();

}
```

Comment: on which line it crashes? share your `toastdesign.xml` also

Comment: where is toast initialized?

Comment: Where is your logcat error ? Have you initialized your `Toast`?

Comment: Have you initialized your Toast and ImageView(iv)?